# If U contains some point in $A_{\alpha'}$, and $A_{\alpha'}$ is connected, then $A_{\alpha'} \subset U$.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is a theorem 5.5, in Croom, topology textbook.

I have a problem with red line. How this can be justified?

> If U contains some point in $A_{\alpha'}$, and $A_{\alpha'}$ is connected, then $A_{\alpha'} \subset U$.

I have trouble with understanding above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $A_{\alpha'}\subseteq U\cup V$. If $A_{\alpha'}\not\subseteq U$, then $A_{\alpha'}\cap V$ would be nonempty, and $A_{\alpha'}\cap U,A_{\alpha'}\cap V$ would be a partition of $A_{\alpha'}$ into nonempty open sets, contradicting $A_{\alpha'}$ being connected.

Comment: But how do we know that $U$ and $V$ are separated?

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat Do you mean disjoint? We don't know that $U,V are, but $A_{\alpha'}\cap U,A_{\alpha'}\cap V$ are since $A_{\alpha'}\cap U\cap A_{\alpha'}\cap V\subseteq U\cap V\cap Y=\varnothing$

Comment: I see... let me think about this first. Meantime I rewrite your answer to make it readable :D))

We don't know that $U$, $V$ are, but $A_{\alpha'}\cap U,A_{\alpha'}\cap V$ are since $A_{\alpha'}\cap U\cap A_{\alpha'}\cap V\subseteq U\cap V\cap Y=\varnothing$.

Comment: So, $A_{\alpha'}$ must be either in $U$ or $V$, but cannot be in both. Is it correct?